# How to get the label values for list fields in Twig?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to fetch the label of the list and display it on the twig template.

Using `node.field_list.value` outputs the key value. I tried using `node.field_list.label` but it returns empty. I tried using `node.field_list.title`, `node.field_list.0.label` or `node.field_list[0]['#markup']` but it still returns empty on the twig template

Comment: Ah, I understand your question properly now from the accepted answer, I was thinking of the field label rather than the human names for the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways:

It calls List allowed values and it stores in the field configuration.

When field cardinality is 1

```
<div>
  {% set list_value = node.filter_list.value %}
  {{ node.filter_list.getSetting('allowed_values')[list_value] }}
</div>
```

When field cardinality is more than 1

```
<div>
  {% set allowed_values = node.filter_list.getSetting('allowed_values') %}
  {% set list_values = node.filter_list.getValue() %}
  {% for list_value in list_values %}
    <div>
      {{ allowed_values[list_value['value']] }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

In case when your template is node.html.twig you can render it based on field formatter in your view mode.

```
<div>
  {{ content.filter_list }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the field is set to `unlimited` and not to `limited`? I tried this `{% set list_value = node.field_list.value %}
              

                {% for list in node.field_list.getSetting('allowed_values')[list_value] %}

                {{ list }}

                {% endfor %}`

but it does not seem to output anything on the loop

Comment: @clestcruz good point, I updated my answer

Comment: Hmm I tried your solution but nothing seems to output within the twig template

Comment: @clestcruz ahh yes, ->value returns only single value, I updated answer, try one more time

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I've been able to display the label of a Single Choice Text List inside a custom Entity referenced on a node with an EntityReference field :

```
{% for entity_ref_item in node.field_my_entity_ref_field %}
  {% set my_choice_key = entity_ref_item.entity.field_my_list_field.value %}
  {% set my_choice_label = entity_ref_item.entity.field_my_list_field.getSettings('allowed_values')['allowed_values'][my_choice_key] %}
  <div>{{ my_choice_label }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I believe that Alex Kuzava's code might have been missing one array ['allowed_values']

```
{{ node.filter_list.getSetting('allowed_values')[list_value] }}
```

might need to be

```
{{ node.filter_list.getSetting('allowed_values')['allowed_values'][list_value] }}
```

instead.
To be sure, you can use devel kint()

```
{{ kint(node.filter_list.getSetting('allowed_values'))}}
```

That's how I found out there was one more array level before getting to the label. But maybe my situation was different because I am accessing a custom entity...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the module [Twig Field Value](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value) to help with this task. Once installed the code:

```
{{ content.field_list|field_label }}
```

should display the label. The way the label is stored and accessed not affected by the field's cardinality.

Comment: I tried using `Twig Field Value` to output the value as you mentioned but it only returns empty. I even tried `{{ node.field_list.value|field_label }}`

Comment: Try using "content" instead of "node". I just checked the comments in the base node template and that's the correct way to get rendered field data.

Comment: Yah I tried that also, the thing it is rendered within `page.html.twig`

Comment: In page.html.twig? That's not where you'd normally render field data directly. If you need to go off-piste it would be better to sort out your data in a preprocess hook instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Drupal9 and did the same as @alex_kuzava. But got a problem with the key, seems that it was an array or something. So this is my answer:

```
{% set list_key = node.field_location_tag[0].value %}
{% set list_value = node.field_location_tag.getSetting('allowed_values')[list_key] %}
{{ list_value }}
```

Notice the [0] before field_location_tag. I don't really know whats happening here but my first clue was that list_key wasn't a string. So I try to apply the |string filter and Drupal told me that I was trying to do an array to string transformation.

I guess is something to do that the content I'm getting is from a lists of nodes inside a paragraphs that are loaded using \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

Or maybe that I'm using the language module. Somehow the value is converted to an array first.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a PHP code solution since Search Engines are leading here

```
private function getListTypeValue($node, $fieldName) {
  $listField = $node->get($fieldName);
  return $listField->getSettings()['allowed_values'][$listField->value] ?? '';
}
```